# Streaming Audio Video

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

We're currenty using Windows Media Services to stream live and on demand audio/video.  We're currently looking for a solution that's more cross-platform compatable (iOS compatable).

I've looked into the new IIS Media Services, but it falls short of what we need.  For live streaming we mostly stream audio only and IIS Media Services doesn't have an audio only option.  Plus on-demand content has to be encoded to their Smooth Stream format, so if you want a downloadable mp4 file you have to have 2 formats.

I've also looked at Real Helix Server and it seems like a real viable solution, but cost seems to be a factor.  We need to archive the live audio feed we broadcast.  With the Helix Server and RealProducer pro I can send the audio to 1 output.  If I use AAC format I get my cross-platform compatability, but the Helix Server won't archive the AAC stream.  We would have to upgrade to RealProducer pro which allows for 2 outputs so I can add an output in Real Media format that can be archived - and I would have to buy a RealProducer license for each computer we would stream from.

Are there any other solutions out there you would recommend?  We're open to hosted solutions as well.

Requirements :

- Cross-platform delivery
- Archiving of live audio stream
- On-demand streaming of mp3/mp4 files

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer that they use wowza media server.  I don't know why that answer isn't showing up here, but I'm glad I subscribed to the RSS feed for answers, or else I would have never got to see it.

Anyway - I've been testing it out and I think it's great.  So far, I like it better than the Helix Universal server.